Why can solana explorer find my token, but solscan can't?
Here you can see it:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/mGeyYGeUEbLVR3d5pAoexBZTJ13PGSSrjYqmsyLn3QZ?cluster=devnet
And here you can't:
https://solscan.io/account/mGeyYGeUEbLVR3d5pAoexBZTJ13PGSSrjYqmsyLn3QZ?cluster=devnet

Solscan takes a while before indexing devnet transactions.
If developing, it's best to use the Solana Explorer and SolanaFM for immediate results on transactions.
